# how to reset debian 11 lxqt desktop configuration

Tags: debian, configuration, dconf, sddm, lxqt

I reinstalled my **Debian 11** and try configure it but everything goes wrong.

[image]

I need to reset it as fresh new.

What i tried :-
dconf-cli command
replace user .config with root .config
but things didn't effect that much.

Comment: well after reboot not everything but most of the thing become stable. maybe because of root user .config folder file.

Comment: Create a new user account, check if it's still an issue. No idea where LXQT stores its config files, so I can't say which ones to move away.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov your comment has solved my problem please post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found was from https://www.publish0x.com/a-bit-of-everything/restore-default-panel-in-lubuntu-2004-xmdjogv :

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/lxqt/panel.conf ~/.config/lxqt/
$ reboot
```

This solution only modifies the relevant config file, and avoids re-creating the user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Credits:- [**Artem S. Tashkinov**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov) comment that solve my problem.

Lxqt stores it config files in `/home/"user name without double quote and white space"/.config/` and the configuration that user made to desktop or task manager or panel are save in `/home/"user name"/.config/lxqt` according to my knowledge.

So, The steps i did to reset my configuration with commands are:-

- Start terminal and become root user.

  - > `sudo su`
- delete a regular user that configuration files you want to reset.

  - > `deluser "user name"`
- add new user

  - > `adduser "user name"`
- give sudo privilege to new user.

  - > `sudo usermod -a -G sudo "user name"`
- restart computer to work all changes perfectly.

  - > `sudo reboot`

That's all.